React STL Viewer capture image
I'm using react-stl-viewer to render STL files for my website. After the file is rendered I want to capture a 2D image for use elsewhere on the website. Is there a way to achieve this using this package?
Here's the provided example code:
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {StlViewer} from "react-stl-viewer";

const url = "https://storage.googleapis.com/ucloud-v3/ccab50f18fb14c91ccca300a.stl"

const style = {
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    width: '100vw',
    height: '100vh',
}

function App() {
    return (
        <StlViewer
            style={style}
            orbitControls
            shadows
            url={url}
        />
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));


Found a solution! If you keep a reference to the canvas element of STLViewer, you can call toBlob() and convert the blob into an image file.
Here's the completed code using the given example:
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { StlViewer } from 'react-stl-viewer';

const url =
  'https://storage.googleapis.com/ucloud-v3/ccab50f18fb14c91ccca300a.stl';

const style = {
  top: 0,
  left: 0,
  width: '100vw',
  height: '100vh',
};

function App() {
  const [viewerElement, setViewerElement] = useState(null);

  const captureThumbnail = () => {
    if (viewerElement) {
      const canvas = viewerElement.querySelector('canvas');
      if (canvas) {
        canvas.toBlob((blob) => {
          const file = new File([blob], "my-snapshot.jpg");
          // Do something with the image file
        });
      }
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (viewerElement) {
      captureThumbnail();
    }
  }, [viewerElement]);

  return (
    <div>
      <div ref={setViewerElement}>
        <StlViewer style={style} orbitControls shadows url={url}/>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

